# Installing and including OpenCV in VSCode on MacOS for c++

Tags: c++, opencv, include

I'm trying to install and use opencv in vscode for c++. I downloaded OpenCV 4.5.5 from https://opencv.org/releases/ but now I don't know how to include opencv in my code.

I tried using:

```
#include <opencv2.framework/opencv2>
```

but I then get the following error message:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgasg.png)

I also tried using:

```
#include <opencv2.framework/Headers/opencv.hpp>
```

but then I get the following error message:

[error message2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpaEo.png)

Other ways of installing OpenCV like using git clone or homebrew have the same result.

Comment: No idea but moving files around to make `#include` work is the wrong approach. The correct approach is to tell your compiler where to find the header files, not to move the header files to a different location.

Comment: It always helps with this kind of question to give four things, 1) actual code which fails to compile, 2) error messages quoted verbatim 3) command used to compile the code 4) actual location of the header files and libraries you are trying to use. Specify those things and you should get an answer pretty quickly. At the moment answering this question requires a bit of guess work.

Comment: @john now you should have more information

Comment: I'm no expert, but I think the correct include is `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`. So write your code like that and if it doesn't work (which it probably won't) then figure out the correct options to give to your compiler to make that include work. As I said earlier that's the correct approach, not trying different includes or copying header files around. What you need to figure out is the options you need to give to your compiler.

Comment: It does not work `'opencv2/opencv.hpp file not found'`. How do I find out what options to give to my compiler ? Is there no alternative? I don't want to give the compiler a bunch of arguments every time I run the code

Comment: You haven't said which compiler you are using, assuming it's g++ then the option would be `-I` e.g. `-Isome/path/somewhere`. Since you are using VSCode you should be able to add those options to your tasks.json file. However frameworks in MacOS are something I know nothing about, so there may be better ways to handle those.